# Firebase returns null photoUrl

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

I am building a mock social media app that allows users upload profile pictures to create their profiles. I am building this app in flutter.
Right now, here's my uploadPic method:

```
Future uploadPic(BuildContext context) async{

    String fileName = basename(_image.path);
    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
    var photoUrl;

    Reference ref = storage.ref().child(fileName);
    var storedImage = File(_image.path);
    UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(storedImage);
    uploadTask.then((res) {
      photoUrl = res.ref.getDownloadURL();
    });


    print("photo url -- $photoUrl");
    await widget.user?.updatePhotoURL(photoUrl);
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.updatePhotoURL(photoUrl);
  }
```

**I have added the right permissions in my firebase console to allow read and write to the database. I know this because when I check firebase storage, I see the pictures have been uploaded successfully.** However, when I try to print the returned photo url (after the upload task completes), I get a null value. This is a problem when I try to access the photo in other areas in the app, because the user photoUrl in firebase is null.

Is there anything I am doing wrong concerning the upload of the pic to firebase?
Also, my terminal returns this: **No App Check token for request.**. I'm wondering if this has anything to do with the issue?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your problem is simple, it's exactly from here:

```
var photoUrl;
uploadTask.then((res) {
   photoUrl = res.ref.getDownloadURL();
});
print(photoUrl); // null
```

the problem is you are trying to print `photoUrl` variable without waiting for the future `uploadTask` to finish its work which results `null`.

the solution is to wait for `uploadTask` future before printing the `photoUrl` variable:

```
var photoUrl;
await uploadTask.then((res) async {
   photoUrl = await res.ref.getDownloadURL();
});
print(photoUrl);
```

the solution on your code:

```
Future uploadPic(BuildContext context) async{

    String fileName = basename(_image.path);
    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
    var photoUrl;

    Reference ref = storage.ref().child(fileName);
    var storedImage = File(_image.path);
    UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(storedImage);
    await uploadTask.then((res) async {
       photoUrl = await res.ref.getDownloadURL();
    });


    print("photo url -- $photoUrl");
    await widget.user?.updatePhotoURL(photoUrl);
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.updatePhotoURL(photoUrl);
  }
```

Comment: You identified the problem correctly (), but the better (and simpler) code for the middle block of six lines would be: `Reference ref = storage.ref().child(fileName); await ref.putFile(storedImage); photoUrl = await ref.getDownloadURL();`, so you can get rid of the `uploadTask` altogether, and don't need a `then()`.

Comment: Thanks so much for spotting that KreatorDev. Clearly I have a thing or two to learn about async functions. Also many thanks @Frank van Puffelen for the optimized code!